# How does my lab's Helium-filled cathode ray tube produce a blue-ish glow?

Tags: atomic-physics, physical-chemistry

In my university's lab, we have typical "e/m apparatus"'s, i.e. a cathode ray tube nested between a Helmholtz coil. Here is the manual for the device we are using.

When operating the device, we typically set the acceleration voltage to around $200 \text{V}-400\text{V}$, so that means the electrons flying in circular trajectories should have kinetic energies around $200 \text{eV}- 400 \text{eV}$. The tube is filled with low-pressure Helium, which gives rise to a blue-ish arc characterizing the electron trajectories.

My understanding is that the free electrons elastically scatter with the Helium atoms, mostly ionizing them. An electron will then join back with the ionized Helium atom, producing a photo-emission. Here are some crucial numbers for inert Helium:

- To excite a single electron by a single level, i.e. $\text{(1s)}^2\rightarrow \text{(1s)(2s)}$: $\color{red}{19.8\,\text{eV}}$.
- To ionize a single electron, i.e. $\text{(1s)}^2\rightarrow \text{(1s)}$: $\color{red}{24.6\,\text{eV}}$
- To ionize two electrons, i.e. $\text{(1s)}^2\rightarrow \text{(no electrons)}$: $\color{red}{79\,\text{eV}}$

None of these energies correspond to wavelengths of visible light (at all!). How then is there a blue-ish glow? Clearly my understanding of what is actually going is flawed.

---

**[Sources]**

[1] Helium energies: https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl

[2] Energy to Wavelength converter: https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/Tools/energyconv/energyConv.pl

[3] Lab Manual: http://www.mhzelectronics.com/ebay/manuals/daedalon_ep-20_em_apparatus_manual.pdf

Comment: Because you don’t need to ionize, only excite.

Comment: See [Hydrogen Spectral Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series), paying particular attention to the difference between the ultraviolet Lyman series and the visible Balmer series.

Comment: @JonCuster Could you expand on that? I included the excitation energy of the first/lowest  transition (ground to first excited) and that even that isn't in the visible spectrum.

Comment: Google He emission spectrum and look at the NIST page.

Comment: @JonCuster You're talking about these right?
 https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/heliumtable2.htm

Comment: @JonCuster I do see that there are a number of emission lines in the blue-ish range, but their existence doesn't totally answer my question. There are a huge number of other emission lines, **many** of which are outside the blue-ish range. Why is it that the spectrum of emission lines excited by the electrons fall **very strongly** near the blue-ish range.